# Psycholinguistics: any interesting studies in personality switching withing language?

Tags: psycholinguistics

I'm workiong on a school project and I want to see if there are any studies made to the following matter.
 We all know what a code siwtch is , I wonder if there's something similar in personality, like switches in believes, values, morals, etc. i want to know anything related to it . I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: This is not about linguistics.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that , I though there was a relationship beetween language and personality and that would be related to either socio or psycolinguistics. Anyway if you do find something let me know. Thanks for answering

Comment: To be honest I have no real idea what you're asking about. You need to explain in more detail, and please fix your typos!

Comment: I think psycholinguistics is on-topic here, but I haven't seen experts in the field answer questions here.

Comment: You mean something like, in English I have a behavior X, in Spanish on the analogue situation I have a behavior Y? I have found, once, a study comparing the effect of "enactment" vs "non-enactment" words in the behavior for instance, things like this, but not related to the language itself. Yet it makes sense for me, as the different language puts you in another cultural context.